# Is it possible to send/receive serial messages from/to Ender 3 mainboards (not USB!)?

Tags: creality-ender-3, electronics, arduino, serial-connection

I want to connect an Arduino or similar MCU board to an Ender 3 mainboard and make them communicate. I don't want to use USB. Are there any pins on the controller boards to achieve this?

I found in the Marlin G-code reference the `M118` (serial print) command, this is ideal for my need, but I don't know to catch its serial messages on the mainboard.

Answer (score 3):

You can solder cables to the RX, TX and GND pins on the mainboard.

There are tutorials on Youtube that describe this.